# Modifying a polytope

Tags: reference-request, linear-programming, polytopes

I'm searching for a reference for the following simple fact about polytopes.

**FACT:**

If $\{x\;|\;Ax \leq b\}$ defines a polytope, and if $c\geq 0$ then 
$\{x\;|\;Ax\leq b+c\}$ also defines a polytope (i.e. a *bounded* polyhedron).

Although this fact is intuitively obvious, and not difficult to prove, I would like to justify it in at most one or two lines of text. So does this fact follows directly as a special case of some well known theorem?

Obs: It is clear that if $Ax\leq b$ is satisfied, then $Ax\leq b+c$ is satisfied. Therefore, the polytope defined by $Ax \leq b$ is included in the **polyhedron** defined by $Ax\leq b+c$. The question is about showing that $Ax\leq b+c$ defines a **polytope**, i.e., a **bounded** polyhedron.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo this is clear. But this only shows that the polytope defined by $Ax \leq b$ is included in the *polyhedron* defined by $Ax\leq b+c$. The question is about showing that $Ax\leq b+c$ defines a *polytope*, i.e., a bounded polyhedron.

Comment: It is not clear what you are after. Since a reference to a theorem is accepted, you're not looking for an intuitive solution, yet a two line proof is unacceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Just observe that the polyhedra 
$P=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n\ |\ Ax\leq b\}$ and $Q=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n\ |\ Ax\leq b+c\}$ have the same recession cone
$$rec(P)=rec(Q)=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n\ |\ Ax\leq 0\}$$. 
By hypothesis $rec(P)=\{\emptyset\}$ because $P$ is a polythope. The thesis follows.